# Show R documentation of a function in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app and I need one of the tabpanels to show the R Documentation of one of the functions of the package RecordLinkage, so the user can choose his argument options.

I have tried

```
library(shiny)
library(RecordLinkage)

ui <- fluidPage(

tabPanel("Literature of functions",

                  selectInput(
                    "literatureChoice",
                    "Choose a function : ",
                    choices = c("compare.dedup",
                                "compare.linkage")
                  ),

                  textOutput("literatureOutput")
         ),
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$literatureOutput <- renderText({
    ?compare.linkage
  })
}
```

But it doesn't show any documentation. I'm aware that **?compare.linkage** shows in help panel in RStudio instead of the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R help documentations are stored in `Rd` objects. We need a way to fetch this object and render them in Shiny.

We fetch the `Rd` object with the help of `Rd_fun()` found in the `gbRd` package.

We then parse the file into html with `Rd2HTML`. The file is saved in the temp directory and read back into R.

The example is for the `reactive()` function found in the `shiny` package, replace it with whichever function required.

```
library(shiny)
library(gbRd)
library(tools)


ui <- fluidPage(

  tabPanel("Literature of functions",

           selectInput(
             "literatureChoice",
             "Choose a function : ",
             choices = c("compare.dedup",
                         "compare.linkage")
           ),

           htmlOutput("literatureOutput")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$literatureOutput <- renderText({
    temp = Rd2HTML(Rd_fun("reactive"),out = tempfile("docs"))
    content = read_file(temp)
    file.remove(temp)
    content
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: oh perfect! Thanks a lot Sada93 :)